# Stretch the glue within a breakable tcolorbox when \flushbottom is used

Tags: page-breaking, tcolorbox, vspace, glue

This question is related to [my other one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/632973/92705). In that question, I describe my attempt to replace `tcolorbox` with another frame drawing technique, which does not introduce problems described below, but creates new ones (though maybe easier to solve for advanced TeX users).

#### Question

When `tcolorbox` needs to be broken, the vertical glue of its inner content does not stretch, resulting in an uneven page layout. How to fix that? I have tried multiple options and failed.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\flushbottom
\newcommand{\object}{\par\tikz[]{\draw (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,3); \node at (\textwidth/2,1.5) {Content}}}

\tcbset{my-frame/.style={
    breakable,
    before skip=\medskipamount,
    after skip=\medskipamount
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[my-frame]
    \object
    \medskip % not stretched
    \object
\end{tcolorbox}
 % stretched too much
\begin{tcolorbox}[my-frame]
    \object
    \medskip % not stretched
    \object
    \medskip % not stretched
    \object
    \medskip % not stretched
    \object
    \medskip % not stretched
    \object
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

#### Illustration

In the picture below, `vspace` between boxes is stretched, while the `vspace` inside them is not:
[image: vspace between boxes is stretched, while the vspace inside them is not.]

#### Expected result

The `vspace`s should be evenly adjusted:
[image: Evenly adjusted spaces]

I think that what I'm asking about is impossible to do with tcolorbox, because it uses something minipage-like underneath. I'd be happy to hear about other box drawing methods which would not introduce such problems. I don't need any fancy features, I just want to be able to draw a colourful background under some paragraphs, like theorems and proofs, which span many pages.