# Footnotes and breakable tcolorbox

Tags: footnotes, page-breaking, tcolorbox

#### Question

My MWE document below has three pages, numbered with 1, 2 and 3, respectively. It contains a long `tcolorbox` environment, which spans all three pages. The box contains a sentence with a footnote. The sentence ends up at page 1. I want to display the corresponding footnote on page 1. How to do that?

[Nearly the same question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263693/footnote-in-a-tcolorbox-environment) was asked a few years ago, but unfortunately it seems to be misunderstood by people who tried to answer it. For that reason, I am asking it again.

#### Failed attempts

1. Just use `\footnote{ ... }`. This approach fails, because the footnote is printed in the middle of page 3, within the box, and it also uses a different counter for numbering. To test that, comment out lines 9-10 in the MWE.
2. Slightly improved approach taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585249/92705): use the `footnotes` package. The footnote gets printed at the end of page 3.
3. Forget about `tcolorbox` and use [less invasive frame drawing method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632973/an-alternative-to-tcolorbox-how-to-specify-vertical-skips) that I came up with. This avoids the problem with footnotes, but adds a number of other ones, which `tcolorbox` handled (e.g., I do not know how to insert exactly the amount of `\vspace` I need, [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632973/an-alternative-to-tcolorbox-how-to-specify-vertical-skips) remains unanswered).

#### Picture

The picture from the question asked a few years ago seems to be fitting. `Footnotemark` is the place where the sentence annotated by footnote is located. In turn, `my footnotetext` is the desired location of the footnote.
[image: picture borrowed from the previous question]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{footnote}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tcolorbox}{\savenotes}
\AfterEndEnvironment{tcolorbox}{\spewnotes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
        \lipsum[1]
        
        {\color{red}The text ends up on page 1, but the footnote does not\footnote{it is incorrectly placed on page 3}.}
        
        \lipsum[2-13]
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution is here:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611262/footnotes-in-tcolorbox-not-in-the-page-of-the-footnotemark?rq=1